# How to change vendor and product name on QEMU?

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt

I am using Libvirt along with QEMU/KVM virtual machine. I wish to change the product name and vendor of my SATA drive but it tells me it can on be used for SCSI drives as seen here:

`Error changing VM configuration: unsupported configuration: Only scsi disk supports vendor and product`

Now, I understand that I have to use SCSI but I cannot due to the fact that it doesn't work under secure boot even when I tried it, and Windows 11 requires secure boot. The only other option I see is passing in a legit and real drive but I wanted to ask if anyone knew before doing such a thing.

here is my current XML code:

```
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
  <source file="/myMedia/Virtual Machines/win11G-1.qcow2"/>
  <target dev="sdd" bus="sata"/>
  <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="3"/>
</disk>
```